# Rotation matrices and angular velocity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, coordinate-systems, rotations

Let us assume I have an object O with axis $x_{O}$, $y_{O}$, $z_{O}$, with different orientation from the global frame S with $x_{S}$, $y_{S}$, $z_{S}$ (I don't care about the position).
Now I know the 3 instantaneous angular velocities of the object O with respect to the same O frame, that is $\omega_O^O = [\omega_{Ox}^O \omega_{Oy}^O \omega_{Oz}^O]$.
How can I obtain this angular velocity with respect to the global frame (that is $\omega_O^S$)?

Thank you!

Comment: Angular velocity is a bivector. Have you considered rotating it by $O$'s orientation (or the inverse) back into the global frame?